# Can I get the DataAnnotation Display Name of a property when I don't know the type?

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I am going to walk through the properties of items in an ICollection and at Compile Time will not necessarily know what type the items in the ICollection will be. I can get the Property name, but would like to get the DataAnnotation Display Name (if any).

**How can I find the Display Name defined in DataAnnotations (if any) of an unknown type at run time?**

So far I have this:

```
foreach (var thisSection in Report.ReportSections)
{
    reportBody.Append(thisSection.ReportSectionName + Environment.NewLine);

    if (thisSection.ReportItems != null)
    {
        var itemType = thisSection.ReportItems.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single();

        var first = true;
        foreach (var prop in itemType.GetProperties())
        {
            if (!first) reportBody.Append(",");

            // This gives me the property name like 'FirstName'
            reportBody.Append(prop.Name); 

            try
            {
                // I'd like to get the Display Name from 
                // [Display(Name = "First Name")]
                var displayName = prop.GetCustomAttributes();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

            first = false;
        }
        reportBody.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

`ReportSection` is defined like this:

```
public interface IReportSection
{
    string ReportSectionName { get; }

    ICollection ReportItems { get; }
}
```

The ICollection could contain a collection of objects like this:

```
public class ProjectAffiliateViewModel
{
    public string Role { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

For the `Role` property we would get `Role`, and for the `FirstName` property we would get `First Name`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
DisplayAttribute attribute = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)
                                 .Cast<DisplayAttribute>()
                                 .SingleOrDefault();

string displayName = (attribute != null) ? attribute.Name : prop.Name;
```